# How to create an IAM user with Programmatic access with Full Access to S3 using the PHP SDK

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I am trying to create a new IAM user (programmatic access only) that has full access to Amazon S3 using PHP SDK.

I looked at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/api/api-iam-2010-05-08.html#createuser and I am not able to figure out what parameter is required to indicate programmatic access only to the user. Does specifying the username alone indicates it to be Programmatic user? Once I create the user, I am assuming, I have to call the "createAccessKey" method for that user to get the access credentials? Is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You are correct**. `createuser` only creates an IAM user without any permissions. By default the user can't do anything, including no programmatic access. To enable the access you have to call `createAccessKey`.

Since the user has no permissions by default, you will also need to add IAM policy to the user with S3 permissions.